# Is current fmt library v9.1.0 backwards compatible to c++17? If not, how far back must I go?

Tags: fmt

I am new to fmtlib and cloned from the head.  I would like to know if v9.1.0 on the head of the repo is backwards compatible with c++17?  The sample project I managed to build with worked perfectly with c++20 ... unfortunately, I have to stay behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The {fmt} library is compatible with C++11 and later. In fact, it only requires a subset of C++11 features. Some optional features may have additional requirements but you don't have to use them.